# Identifying someone as being Jewish

Tags: halacha

How many generations back is one allowed to go to identify himself as being Jewish? If a Jew converts to another religion, he is still Jewish and his descendants are Jewish.

Does this mean that if someone can prove that he can trace his ancestry to Jacob, even though, somewhere, say, 10 generations following Jacob, his ancestor became Hindu, this person would still be Jewish?

(Please assist in tagging.)

Comment: If he can trace has ancestry back to Jacob through an unbroken line of mothers, then why not?

Comment: Actually, you would only need to trace it back to the revelation at Sinai through an unbroken chain of mothers and also prove that none of the women in that chain had a non-Jewish divorce and remarriage. I doubt that it can be done. As little as four generations has proven (almost) impossible.